# Sequelize include query without child attributes

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I've been trying to figure out if its possible to do a query with include when I don't need any of the child attributes to be returned Example Setup:

```
@Table
export class Parent extends Model {
 @PrimaryKey
 @Column
 ID: number
 ....
}

@Table
export class Child extends Model{
 @PrimaryKey
 @Column
 ID: number
 @PrimaryKey
 @BelongsTo(()=>Parent,{ as: 'parent', targetKey: 'ID', foreignKey: 'PARENT_ID' })
 @Column
 PARENT_ID: number
.....
}
```

and then in some class I run

```
@Injectable()
export class ModelService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Child)
    private childModel: typeof Child,
  ) {}

 findAll(){
   const res = this.childModel.findAll({
    attributes: [], //because I don't need any from child attributes
    include: Parent,
    .....,
   })
 }
}
```

Although the query does return results the dataValues property of each row in res is empty where I would have expected that each row will have parent property.

even if I add one column to the attributes key of the child model in the query then it does work as intended.

any clues on how to resolve this?

NOTE: I've already tried putting required on the parent model in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use join, like this:

```
const res = this.childModel.findAll({
  include: Parent,
  includeIgnoreAttributes: false,
});
```

Comment: hey @sptmru thanks for trying to help but join is not a valid option
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'join' does not exist in type 'FindOptions<any>'.ts(2345)

Comment: @AmirShaneh hey! Yeah, that was wrong. Please try updated answer.

Comment: Again thanks for trying to help but this is another invalid option
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'includeIgnoreAttributes' does not exist in type 'FindOptions<any>'.ts(2345)